# HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session not updating correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side

I am currently using a session variable to store the number of articles in a cart.

I access it like this in my page

Content of the `cart.cshtml`

```
@{
   string nbArticles = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("NbArticles");
}
<p>@nbArticles</p>
```

Content of `cartinfo.cshtml` calling the component

```
<component type="typeof(ShoppingCart)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Content of the `ShoppingCart.razor` file :

```
void UpdateCart(int nb)
{
  //Get current number of articles
  int nbArticles = Int32.Parse(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("NbArticles"));
  //Add new item
  nbArticles += nb;
  //Set new number to session
  HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("NbArticles", nbArticles.ToString());
}
```

It is working properly, no errors are thrown or anything. However, when I change pages, the cshtml is called, with the `GetString` call and the number retrieved is not updated. But if I reload the page the correct number is retrieved.

For exemple.

- In the blazor component NbArticles is equal to `2`
- I call `UpdateCart(1)`
- NbArticles is now equal to `3`
- The Session is set to `3`
- I go to `cart.cshtml` and it calls  `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("NbArticles")`
  -> I get `2` instead of `3`
- I reload the page thus re-calling `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("NbArticles")` and I finally get `3`

Am I missing a configuration or something that causes the sessions to have latency refreshing ?

Comment: Hi @CodingNewb, how do you use the razor view with blazor component? Please share more details.

Comment: I don't think using `Session` is supported (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12432). Pick one of these instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0 ?

Comment: @Rena I added info about how I use the components in my MVC application

Comment: Hi @CodingNewb, It could work well in my project by using your code, what is the difference is that i change to `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"`. But that is because if I use `render-mode="Server"` it will not display any html code.

Comment: @Rena the problem is not in the razor component itself, it is in the cshtml when it retrieves the session, it is not up to date until I refresh the page a second time.

Comment: Hi @CodingNewb, yes, it works well in my project and no need reload the page.